# On SQL what would be the best way to do formulas?

Tags: sql, formula

I have the following structure

[Columns structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfpNY.png)

The date columns contain hours as well. I need to calculate the time beetween start and date on the same case number.

Example if case 1 has 2 subcases I need to calculate from the start date of the first one until the end date of the second one and add that to another column as "actual fixed time".

The thing is there could be 2 or 10 or 20 or more subcases.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Also, post text as text, not pictures of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use [DATEDIFF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) in conjunction with [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date)) as ActualFixedTime FROM YourTable GROUP BY Casenumber
```

This will give you your actual fixed time for each case. In order to display this result for each row of your subcases, you join on it when selected your table:

```
SELECT YourTable.*, FixedTimes.ActualFixedTime
FROM YourTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT Casenumber,
                DATEDIFF(hour, MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date)) AS ActualFixedTime
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY Casenumber)
    AS FixedTimes
    ON YourTable.Casenumber = FixedTimes.Casenumber
```

Comment: You're assuming OP is using Microsoft SQL Server.